# HListView failed to instantiate Android Eclipse Project Library

Tags: android, android-listview, android-library

The library includes a demo project, i tried and it worked pretty nice. Now when i imported the library in my project, in my layout file i added:

```
<it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView
        android:id="@+id/hListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp" >
    </it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView>
```

It is almost same as in the demo, and i get the following error when i go to graphical layout tab.

```
    eclipse.buildId=v22.0.5-757759triedm
    java.version=1.6.0_27
    java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
    BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

    Error
    Tue Nov 26 13:25:53 EET 2013
    it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView failed to instantiate.

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find resource 'hlv_overscroll_edge'
        at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.EdgeEffect.<init>(EdgeEffect.java:144)
        at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AbsHListView.setOverScrollMode(AbsHListView.java:697)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3237)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3295)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:427)
        at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:224)
        at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.AbsHListView.<init>(AbsHListView.java:630)
        at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView.<init>(HListView.java:151)
        at it.sephiroth.android.library.widget.HListView.<init>(HListView.java:147)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(ProjectCallback.java:422)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:179)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
        at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:718)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:372)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:383)
        at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
        at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.reloadLayoutSwt(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1777)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener.access$0(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1715)
        at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$ReloadListener$1.run(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1709)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3537)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3189)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1053)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:942)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

I tried restarting/cleaning, checking paths; but nothing worked.
what could be the issue? or what should i look into the demo project, to make it similar to mine, so that it works?

---

Update

Here is my layout: http://pastebin.com/L7d5idwE

Comment: post your whole xml file..

Comment: i posted it on pastebin, as it is too long. Please take a look.

Comment: you have to add xmlns: of that library in top layout for example xmlns:ProgressWheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: http://pastebin.com/1199jUvT
here is the layout which works. i tried adding xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same exception with this library. In my case, I was renaming my manifest package with `aapt`'s `--rename-manifest-package` option. This caused the `HListView`'s `EdgeEffect` class to fail to find required resources because [Resources#getIdentifier(String,String,String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) requires the original package name to load an identifier, rather than the renamed package name. I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView/pull/58) to fix this issue.

Comment: I hope your answer will help someone, but still i think this library is not best thing one could use; i hope i finish the HorizontalListVIew library i started, which could be used and help others. But for now, i couldn't find any good one

Comment: Why? It seems fine to me.

Comment: I will give it a try and update my app, as my solution i used before does not meet the requirements. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlns:HListView="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

add this in reletivelayout it will work

Comment: then check in demo what they added in xmlns

Comment: pastebin.com/1199jUvT 
this is the demo's layout. i couldnt find anything that could help

Comment: log cat showing something you missed  hlv_overscroll_edge resource did u checked

Answer (score 0):

I used scrollView and set items `gone` when i need. I would not recommend using this library, as it is very unstable and could lead to further application problems.